# DETAIL: Views containing UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT are not automatically updatable in Odoo 15

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo-15

I already have basic knowledge in SQL and I need to perform it in Odoo 15.

I want to create a list view using SQL and the datas are from two different model.
sale.order.receivable.lines and account.move.line.

I already display the data.
[image]

but when I go to payment menu and set to draft the record, this error appears.
[image]

Comment: The HINT line of the error message tells you **exactly** what to do, create an `instead of` trigger. See documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html.)